# Would using optional parameters in a repository interface be considered bad design?

Tags: c#, .net, repository-pattern

I have created two classes to externally control page number (`Page`) and ordering (`Order`) on a repository. The repository exposes `IEnumerable<T>` and not `IQueryable<T>` since I want the repository to have strong testability.

Say, for example, if I had the following repository:

```
interface IUserRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<User> GetAll();
}
```

If I want the *caller* to control the subset of the response, they would need to pass in the page/order. So first thought would be to add overloads:

```
interface IUserRepository
{
    IEnumerable<User> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<User> GetAllOrderedAndPaged(Order order, Page page);
}
```

The problem I find with this is that I have to create multiple overloads which I find to be pretty tedious.

What I'm thinking (but not sure) of doing is having `Order` and `Page` be optional parameters:

```
interface IUserRepository
{
    IEnumerable<User> GetAll(Order order = null, Page page = null);
}
```

This way the calling code can easily sort/page, but not play with the *main query* (which is what I'm trying to avoid by exposing `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`).

Does this seem like a good or bad design? I know that could be considered a bit subjective, but I'm trying to see if there is functionally wrong with this. The main key is that my repositories are testable and the caller can't play around/change the query too much. I figured that since sorting/ordering are a *very* common task for a returning set of data, why not incorporate them into the design of the repository interface. Again, when testing, I only care that the *right* set of data is returned, but the caller can say "Now, give me this page/ordered subset of the data".

Comment: Why would you assume it's not OK?

Comment: @Kirk - Considering the fact that I want this to be easily testable, I'm curious to know if this violate any related principles for testing it? I'm just trying to get some feedback of this design since I have not seen it through any Google results.

Comment: But again, why would default values for parameters make it less testable?

Comment: @Kirk - Well I'm not totally sure why it wouldn't, that's why I'm asking this question. I'm trying to gather as much information for and against this design so I can make a proper decision.

Comment: Also - I've never seen optional parameters used, so it really perked my interest as to why it wasn't a common practice.

Comment: @TheCloudlessSky Well, it hasn't been a common practice **in C#** because optional parameters were only added to the language as of the latest version (4.0). It's been common practice in VB for ages. :)

Comment: @djaconbson - Yeah I understand optional parameters are common, since I used to program in VB, but I'm just wondering more about the repository side of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to use both parameters as properties on the repository itself. Taking into consideration the fact that the default value will be compiled into the caller, but also the fact that writing these parameters on *every* method on every possible repository could be tedious.

Answer (score 2):

I would caution against using optional parameters since the default values will be compiled into the caller.  This means that if the default values ever change, any code that uses the original default values will need to be recompiled.

This could be a problem in your specific example if, in the future, you decided that `null` wasn't a valid value, changed the defaults, and started throwing a `ArgumentNullException` if `null` was passed in.  Any code that uses your interface will have to recompiled or potentially start throwing `ArgumentNullExceptions`.

You can read a much better explanation of this [here](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/10/31/c-4-0-feature-focus-part-1-optional-parameters.aspx) and [here](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/05/18/caveats-of-c-4-0-optional-parameters.aspx).

> The key take-away from this: once you expose a default parameter value on a public method, you can never change it without recompiling all clients that depend on it. For library writers, this never means *never ever*.

Comment: That's a very good point to take into consideration. The important thing to note though is that by *default* there *shouldn't* be paging or ordering, so in my case, I think it makes sense to have null as the default and it wouldn't really change. But, this is something I completely forgot about and I'm glad you brought it up.

Answer (score 0):

For my style of programming with a lot of lambda's optional parameters are not well suitable.

**C# 4.0 Features – Named & Optional Parameters – Uh, no thanks:**
http://blogs.ijw.co.nz/chris/index.php/2010/05/c-4-0-features-named-optional-parameters-uh-no-thanks/

As a better design I would use a tuple as parameter. Or named class that aggregate page and order with default fields values. 
Sorry it's of course subjective.

Comment: Sure - I understand the arguments for not using optional parameters for lambdas, but we're talking specifically for a repository interface. There is a 99% guarantee that a repository call *won't* be called from inside some lambda.

Comment: I don't understand this logic. How methods "for a repository interface" differ from others... Are you expect that lamdbas are for using only with collections? For example I usually wrap any repository method into "log start, finish, fault" wrapper exactly using lambda syntax.